# Prove that continuous functions mapping irrationals to rationals must be constant

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function 
such that any irrational number is mapped to a rational number. Then $f$ must be a constant.

Well, the context isn't that much, I was reading some interesting function constructions on Hardy's book. Then raised this question.

As the solution suggest it is an elementary exercise. But definitely interesting.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For convenience, let $\mathbb{I} = [0,1]\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$, which is uncountable, and $\mathbb{J} = [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable.

- $f(\mathbb{I}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is countable.
- $f(\mathbb{J})$ is countable since $\mathbb{J}$ is.

So $f([0,1])=f(\mathbb{I})\cup f(\mathbb{J})$ is countable.

Now, $[0,1]$ is an interval, and the image of an interval by a continuous function is an interval. So $f([0,1])$ is a *countable* interval, which means...

Comment: Ahhh, that's it, I knew it has to be something to do with cardinals, didn't figure out how.

Comment: It is, I believe, a quite classic exercise, so it may be a good idea to remember the "trick."

Comment: Nice solution! +1. May I ask you one moment: why $f(\mathbb{J})$ is countable since $\mathbb{J}$ is countable?

Comment: @RFZ Since (the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{J}$) $f|_{\mathbb{J}}$ is a surjection from $\mathbb{J}$ to $f(\mathbb{J})$, [the cardinality of its codomain is at most the cardinality of its domain.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Cardinality_of_the_domain_of_a_surjection)

Comment: @ClementC., What about the following? If $S$ is a countable set $\{s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots\}$ then $f(S)$ is also countable since it has form $\{f(s_1), f(s_2), \dots\}$

Comment: @RFZ I don't understand what your comment is meant to be. Are you trying to give another proof of this statement, a counterexample...?

Comment: Sorry sometime i have problems with English. I am trying to give another proof as I wrote above

Comment: The comments are probably not the best place for this, but yes, one can also give a direct proof. In that case, you'll need to describe an injective function from $f(\mathbb{J})$ to $\mathbb{J}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40806/discussion-between-rfz-and-clement-c).